# Building MicroSIP 3.20.7: Showing error "Unresolved External Symbols"

Tags: c++, sip, pjsip, visual-studio-2022, pjsua2

I am trying to build **MicroSIP** version **3.20.7** for **Windows 10 64-bit Operating System**.

I already build **PjProject** (As mentioned in the documentation) and obtained all the .lib files for the same and now I am trying to use those .lib files for building **MicroSIP** as mentioned in the documentation over their website.

But I fall for an error of **Unresolved External Symbols** that is **LNK2019 / LNK2001 / LNK1120**.

**(An image for the reference have been attached)**

*I am concluding with following steps.*

1. Download the source for PjProject and extract the source using 7Zip.
2. Added a **config_site.h** file in the **pjlib\include\pj**.
3. Using Visual Studio 2022, Open PjProject and select **pjsua** as the source project.
4. Setting up the configuration for the project as -> Debug-Static for x64. and Build.
5. After a successfull build I got all the .lib files for the PjProject and successfully deployed the **pjsua** project showing a cli menu for **PjSIP**.
6. Now, I downloaded the latest source of **MicroSIP 3.20.7** from the official website and extracted the source code using 7Zip.
7. Setting the configuration for the project as Debug for x64, and including all the header files and library files from windows kit as well as the other media libraries to the **Include Directories and Library Directories {Opus, SDL2, FFMPEG,x264, VPX, PjProject}**
8. I started to build the MicroSIP 3.20.7 and obtained the MicroSIP.lib file successfully.

But at the last where the build must give an executable file for MicroSIP, there are the list of error stating *Unresolved External Symbols {LNK2019 / LNK2001 / LNK1120}*

Below is the link to the image having all the error in console windows.

[image]

The error states the following message.

1. unresolved external symbol pjmedia_get_vid_subsys referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::OnTimer(unsigned __int64)" (?OnTimer@CmainDlg@@QEAAX_K@Z)
2. unresolved external symbol pjmedia_vid_dev_refrence referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::OnTimer(unsigned __int64)" (?OnTimer@CmainDlg@@QEAAX_K@Z).

**etc** there are other 17 error **(*Kindly take the refrence of above image.*)**

Below is the link to the image having error logged in output tab.

[image]

---

**These are the message logged into the output tab**

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: microsip, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>AAOptionsDlg.cpp
1>AccountDlg.cpp
1>AddDlg.cpp
1>addons.cpp
1>BaseDialog.cpp
1>ButtonDialer.cpp
1>Calls.cpp
1>CListCtrl_Sortable.cpp
1>CListCtrl_SortItemsEx.cpp
1>ClosableTabCtrl.cpp
1>Contacts.cpp
1>Dialer.cpp

1>C:\msys64\home\coral\tmp\sources\MicroSIP-3.20.7-src\lib\MessageBoxX.h(38,1): warning C4005: '_NODISCARD': macro redefinition (compiling source file Contacts.cpp)

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\vcruntime.h(319): message : see previous definition of '_NODISCARD' (compiling source file Contacts.cpp)

1>global.cpp
1>IconButton.cpp
1>jumplist.cpp
1>CListCtrl_ToolTip.cpp
1>CMask.cpp
1>Crypto.cpp
1>CSVFile.cpp
1>Hid.cpp
1>json_reader.cpp
1>json_value.cpp
1>json_writer.cpp
1>langpack.cpp
1>LevelsSliderCtrl.cpp
1>Markup.cpp
1>MessageBoxX.cpp
1>ModelessMessageBox.cpp
1>MSIP.cpp
1>StdioFileEx.cpp

1>C:\msys64\home\coral\tmp\sources\MicroSIP-3.20.7-src\lib\MessageBoxX.h(38,1): warning C4005: '_NODISCARD': macro redefinition (compiling source file lib\MessageBoxX.cpp)

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\vcruntime.h(319): message : see previous definition of '_NODISCARD' (compiling source file lib\MessageBoxX.cpp)

1>utf.cpp
1>VisualStylesXP.cpp
1>mainDlg.cpp
1>MessagesDlg.cpp
1>microsip.cpp
1>Preview.cpp
1>RinginDlg.cpp
1>settings.cpp
1>SettingsDlg.cpp
1>ShortcutsDlg.cpp
1>StatusBar.cpp
1>Transfer.cpp

1>   Creating library C:\msys64\home\coral\tmp\sources\MicroSIP-3.20.7-src\x64\Debug\microsip.lib and object C:\msys64\home\coral\tmp\sources\MicroSIP-3.20.7-src\x64\Debug\microsip.exp

1>mainDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjmedia_get_vid_subsys referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::OnTimer(unsigned __int64)" (?OnTimer@CmainDlg@@QEAAX_K@Z)

1>mainDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjmedia_vid_dev_refresh referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::OnTimer(unsigned __int64)" (?OnTimer@CmainDlg@@QEAAX_K@Z)

1>mainDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_enum_devs referenced in function "public: int __cdecl CmainDlg::VideoCaptureDeviceId(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >)" (?VideoCaptureDeviceId@CmainDlg@@QEAAHV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)

1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_enum_devs

1>mainDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_codec_set_priority referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::PJCreateRaw(void)" (?PJCreateRaw@CmainDlg@@QEAAXXZ)

1>mainDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_codec_get_param referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::PJCreateRaw(void)" (?PJCreateRaw@CmainDlg@@QEAAXXZ)

1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_codec_get_param

1>mainDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_codec_set_param referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CmainDlg::PJCreateRaw(void)" (?PJCreateRaw@CmainDlg@@QEAAXXZ)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_preview_param_default referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Preview::Start(int)" (?Start@Preview@@QEAAXH@Z)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_preview_start referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Preview::Start(int)" (?Start@Preview@@QEAAXH@Z)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_preview_get_win referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Preview::Start(int)" (?Start@Preview@@QEAAXH@Z)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_preview_stop referenced in function "protected: void __cdecl Preview::OnDestroy(void)" (?OnDestroy@Preview@@IEAAXXZ)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_win_get_info referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Preview::Start(int)" (?Start@Preview@@QEAAXH@Z)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_win_set_pos referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Preview::Start(int)" (?Start@Preview@@QEAAXH@Z)

1>Preview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_win_set_size referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Preview::Start(int)" (?Start@Preview@@QEAAXH@Z)

1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol pjsua_vid_enum_codecs referenced in function "protected: virtual int __cdecl SettingsDlg::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@SettingsDlg@@MEAAHXZ)

1>C:\msys64\home\coral\tmp\sources\MicroSIP-3.20.7-src\x64\Debug\microsip.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals

1>Done building project "microsip.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the following that what I have tried to solve these errors.

- Checked for the correct linking of Include files to Include directory.
- Checked for the correct linking of Library files to Library directory.
- Checked the name of library and executable files in both PjSIP and MicroSIP

But stills the same error is present.
It's been over a week that I'm scratching my head for this and atlast I am asking, so kindly look into my problem and provide a legit guidance to get rid of these errors from my project.

I am using Visual Studio 2022.
I am using latest version of Windows Kit for Windows 10 that is 10.0.20348.0.

What shall I do next to get a MicroSIP executable file, from building the project from source ?

Comment: Are your libraries debug or release build?

Comment: I hope someone ask for this, All the libraries have build format like:  "libraryname-x86_64-x64-Debug-Static.lib", although I tried to figure out the solution through Release build but still stucking in the same problem.

Comment: These are the errors, but when you build, the build command, etc. can be logged into Output tab. Is there any message logged there which may indicate the root cause? Or maybe the command used for compiling?

Comment: I had edited my post and included the the Output tab image in my post, Kindly take the reference of above mentioned image of the output tab.

Comment: Instead of pasting the image of the output tab, please copy and paste the entire message within the post itself, in the image some output is clipped.

Comment: Done with the editing in post, you can able to check the output messages more broadly.

Comment: You have built the library pj in Debug-Static for x64. Why not simply Debug? Debug Static probably leads to using static runtime and Debug leads to using dynamic runtime (DLL). I am not sure if that causes an issue, but that's one difference I noticed.

Comment: While compiling MicroSIP, after I included the libraries, there is an error asking to include "LIBRARY_NAME-x86_64-x64-Debug-Static.lib", for the further progress in building. This is the only format what MicroSIP is asking to include library file in.

Comment: Can you paste that exact error message: include "LIBRARY_NAME-x86_64-x64-Debug-Static.lib? Also, please include the original configuration that leads to this error.

Comment: I just got a solution and for the better judgement of other devs I want to share it too. The problem that is arising is, the use of video while compiling the PjProject the video modules have not been used and modified correctly, so for the best practice, We need to disable video from the MicroSIP, for doing this small task the needed is, **** Removing the GLOBAL_VIDEO tag from the from the const.h file. **** This will solve the errors but still I can't be able to use the video in MicroSIP and that is the another issue that needed to be solve to get the complete hands on MicroSIP.

Comment: If you have a working solution, you can post a self-answer so that it can help other devs. But, I suggest you look at how you are compiling and linking the libraries. If the libraries used are open source, then their public repo should have proper instructions to build and link the library in applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I figured out what was wrong in the project.

If we don't want to use video option we can terminated the ***Global_Constant_Video*** option in **constant.h**, which will surely build the application but without Video support in it.
If enabling video is an option that need to be opted therefore, you need to clean and rebuild the **PJSUA Cli Menu Application** again by Adding video support to it along with the preferred video codec and use the obtained libraries to build the **MicroSIP** application from the starting.

Hope you find it easy, Just be involved with the codes.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It might be missing

```
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1
```

in config_site.h.

Comment: Already mentioned in the config_site.h, but still showing the error in Video section.